# What are the requirements for the achievements in Ticket to Ride: Europe?

Tags: online, ticket-to-ride-europe

In the electronic ['pocket' version](http://www.daysofwonder.com/online/en/t2r/europe-pocket/) of Ticket to Ride: Europe, I would like to acquire all the achievements, but I must have misunderstood some of them. Even when I think I've accomplished them, I do not get them. In particular:

- "*win while connecting all 4 surrounding countries*"- which 4 countries are we talking about, surrounding what? Each other? Like Austria, Hungary, Italy and Croatia e.g.?
- "*win without claiming any tunnel route*". I've won many times without using a single tunnel, but still no achievement. A route can be finished with or without tunnels, but does this requirement mean that when I get the map, there is no possible tunnel involved between the two cities?

Comment: I assume you're talking about an electronic version of the game.  If someone here can answer, great.  Otherwise, you might want to try asking on our sister site devoted to video games, arqade.com.

Comment: thanks for the advise! I did not know that the achievements are only in the electronic version....

Comment: This question is valid on both sites.  Arqade is a much larger site but boardgame questions aren't the focus there.  Feel free to ask your questions on whichever site makes the most sense for you.

Answer (score 2):

The basic requirement is to purchase the Switzerland map expansion as an in-app purchase and complete the achievements using that map.

For the achievement **Chocolate Exporter** you must connect all four countries (France, Germany, Austria, and Italy). To complete this, priority number one is to actually connect the four countries. This will take most of your trains and many of your turns. Try and grab as many country tickets as you can, but don't push it, they're relatively high value. Avoid non-country tickets as you probably won't have enough trains to complete them.

Here is an example board showing a victory with all four countries connected
[image: Winning with all four countries connected]

and here is the achievement
[image: Chocolate Exporter achievement]

---

For the achievement **Valley Commuter** you must not claim any tunnel routes on the Switzerland map. To complete this, grab as many tickets as you can that can be completed without a tunnel. It's relatively easy to connect most of the cities that don't require tunnels, at which point many of the tickets you will grab will be already completed.

Here is an example board showing a victory with no tunnel routes claimed
[image: Winning without using a tunnel]

and here is the achievement
[image: Valley Commuter achievement]